# Including a Child (Lookup) Table in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

Using Azure OpenAI / Cognitive Search, I want a table in Azure SQL Server to be exposed to Cognitive Search using the "Bring Your Own Data" approach. However, I would like a child table with lookup data to be available as a search filter. So say the main table can have one or more countries in the child table. How do I get the index to be aware of the child table data, without doing a join and duplicating all the rows in the main table?

I guess it's using `Collection(Edm.String)` - but I'm not sure how I project that from my db model into the index.

Currently I'm just directly linking the index to a view, but I'm probably going to link it directly to the table so I can use SQL Server's change detection policies to update the index incrementally. If I have to do a bunch of preprocessing then presumably this change detection strategy becomes void.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support over **4 years** ago; you really need to get that finalised upgrade plan implemented ASAP. Presumably, this instance is hosted in Azure, as this is an Azure question, which means you got a few more years of security patches (at a significant expense), but even that has ended now.

Comment: @ThomA sorry, wrong tag